# Removing "Password protected" option from custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is it possible to remove "password protected" option from the visibility using a hook?

I found the following hook, but it seems I can only check the status of the post.

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'my_function_to_check_status', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Hi! I answered your question below, but never received any feedback on it. If it helped answer your question could you mark it as the correct answer? It's the big tick under the voting buttons, it'd be a huge help!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you can remove that option through a filter or an action (I stand to be corrected though), so you will probably have to action in either CSS or some jQuery to hide it for you.

You can do this with a hook in your functions file (*see code below*)

With jQuery you can fully remove the option, but CSS will only hide it.

---

#### The jQuery Route

```
//load jquery into footer to remove password protected option from visibility
add_action('admin_footer', 'hide_visibility_jquery');
function hide_visibility_jquery() {
    //don't add this script if on any other post type:
    if (get_post_type() != 'my-custom-post-type-slug') { return; }

    //echo the jQuery to remove the input field and its label
    echo '
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(\'input#visibility-radio-password\').remove();
        jQuery(\'label[for="visibility-radio-password"]\').remove();
    </script>
    ';
}
```

---

#### The CSS Route

```
//load CSS into the header to remove password protected option from visibility
add_action('admin_head', 'hide_visibility_css');
function hide_visibility_css() {
    //don't add this CSS if on any other post type:
    if (get_post_type() != 'my-custom-post-type-slug') { return; }
    //echo the CSS to hide the input field and its label
    echo '<style type="text/css">input#visibility-radio-password, label[for="visibility-radio-password"] {display: none;}</style>';
}
```